# Deleted Grub: Laptop's Now Dead

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, grub

After installing Linux alongside Windows, I made a boneheaded move and used `gparted` to delete the Windows partition. Now, all I have is a laptop that boots up and provides this...and only this:

```
error: no such partition
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> ls
(hd0)
grub rescue>
```

I can't boot from the Linux live CD or from a bootable flash drive, even though I have that boot sequence set in the `bios`. If I cld boot from the CD, then I cld at least save my files. That's my only concern at this point; I've already purchased a new laptop.

I've read all the posts here regarding this issue. Nothing suggested in them works for me. It's a Sony Vaio, and I've already tried booting up striking the `F11` key to force a flash drive boot up. Nothing. Can someone instruct me on how to boot up from the live CD or flash drive?

Comment: What word is “cld” suppose to be?  You used it in two different cases and different contexts

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed linux or it came out of the box??

If it came out of the box, please use a UEFI bootable thumbdrive to boot your computer from and then repair the linux's installation.

OR

In case you have installed then use same bootable media to repair the linux installation.

Same can be done with windows.

Comment: I installed Linux from a flash drive onto a hard drive that already had windows on it. And now that I've deleted the partition windows was on, I can't even boot up using that flash drive. The computer gets stuck at the `grub rescue` prompt.

Comment: Is your machine has UEFI based bios!!??

Comment: No, it isn't. I have both a flash drive and a CD with the Linux install on them. I have the boot sequence set to External, then Optical Drive, and lastly the hard drive. Even using both flash drive and CD at the same time, I can't get past the grub rescue screen. Again, when I list (ls), all I get is (hd0). In all I've read there, I'm the only one who gets (hd0) only. Others show other partitions. It's really weird how none of the install media (flash drive and CD) work when i boot up. Goes to the grub rescue screen and that's as far as I can get. I'm open to trying anything at this point.